# Displaying system information on the desktop similar to BGInfo

Tags: java, desktop-application

I'm just wondering if there is a way to display information in a way that it is attached to the desktop (pretty much exactly the same as the program BGInfo) where I can display system information and update it with a given interval.

Answer (score 0):

I think is possible. Your question can be divided into two separates parts:
1 - Collect information to show
2 - Set desktop background

For part #1, depends on type of information you can collect.

For part #2 you can use something like this (for OSX):

```
    private void setDesktopPicture(File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    String as[] = {
            "osascript", 
            "-e", "tell application \"Finder\"", 
            "-e", "set desktop picture to POSIX file \"" + file.getAbsolutePath() + "\"",
            "-e", "end tell"
    };

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(as);

    process.waitFor();
}
```

Similar approach can be used to set desktop background on other systems.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'm sure I can find resources in many places regarding the collection of information, but for the displaying part I was looking to do this for a windows machine, kinda similar to Conky for Linux, any ideas for windows?. Thank you for your help so far as it will definitely help.

Comment: I was also looking to avoid updating the actual background image as well as that would involve writing to the disk every update.

Comment: An alternative to change desktop background image is to use a borderless window located in your desired position. I think you can see JFrame#setFocusable() and setFocusableWindowState(), also is possible you need to use Win32 API. Sorry I doesn't find at this moment any own code where I used.

Comment: The idea is create a window with no border, no moveable and no focusable so from user point of view really is a "background".